# mysqli connection error across servers using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to connect to MySQL database which is on another server using PHP connection. I am getting the following error and can not figure it out.

**This is the error when I include the port:**

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2005):
>   Unknown MySQL server host 'xxxxxx.db.0000095.hostedresource.com:3306'
>   (25) in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/tools/include/db_connect.php on line
>   3 Failed to connect to MySQL: Unknown MySQL server host
>   'xxxxxxxx.db.0000095.hostedresource.com:3306' (25)

---

**This is my error when not using the port:**

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2003):
>   Unknown MySQL server host 'xxxxxx.db.0000095.hostedresource.com'
>   (110) in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/tools/include/db_connect.php on line
>   3 Failed to connect to MySQL: Unknown MySQL server host
>   'xxxxxxxx.db.0000095.hostedresource.com' (110)

---

**This is my db_connect file:**

```
<?
$con=mysqli_connect("xxxxxx.db.0000095.hostedresource.com","xxcorrectxx","xxcorrectxx",
"xxcorrectxx");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

---

Is this a possible firewall issue on the server I have the include file on?
This db connect file is working fine on other domains I have.
Please tell me if you can see a fix for this. Thank you.

Comment: I think the `xxxxxx` part in your MySQL Host needs to be replaced with the actual value.

Comment: does the web server you are connecting `from` have permission to connect to the target sql database server? did you create a db user with `%` for the host?

Comment: @AmalMurali GoDaddy shared hosting strips out sensitive/resolved hostname/user information like that.

Comment: xxxxxx is just a value I have used to block out my actual db name. I have the correct info there.

Comment: Lathesan, not sure what you mean. I am using this exact same code on one site and everything connects just fine. I have not changed permissions on the site where the mysql server is. When I have put the files in another host it is not connecting.

Answer (score 4):

The traffic is blocked by firewall, probably.

Normally MySQL port is NOT open to public access; it is available for local network only. Moreover, the DB user is probably having `localhost` or an IP instead of any host ( `%` ) in the MySQL user permission table.

You can verify by telnet to 3306 port in the remote server.

Comment: I had this issue a while back, whilst trying to connect to 3306 via Navicat. I was running the cPanel interface then, so I had a GUI to follow, and this worked. +1

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation of mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) the port is an additional parameter.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("xxxxxx.db.0000095.hostedresource.com",
  "xxcorrectxx","xxcorrectxx", "xxcorrectxx", 3306);
```

Comment: Optional parameter, [3306 being mysql default](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3736420/46675).

Comment: I was about to add that this should not be nessecary since 3306 is the default port.