# PHP - MySQL connection for specified port settings

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I've got my own DB.php and it was working before I changed the MySQL Port to something else other than 3306 which is default. It fails to connect now; I've configured the DB.php after port change like below :

```
class DB {
//    server    
    private $host = "192.168.1.15";
    private $uname = "user";
    private $pw = "iamuser";
    private $dbname = "matlab";
    private $con = null;
    private $port = "669";

public function __construct() {
        $this->con = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->port, $this->uname, $this->pw);
        if (!$this->con) {
            $this->db_error("Cannot connect to DBMS");
        }
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'latin5'", $this->con);
        mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'latin5'", $this->con);
        mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'latin5_turkish_ci'", $this->con);
        mysql_select_db($this->dbname, $this->con) or db_error("Can not connect to Database");
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how I can make it work with the port number 669 again?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you change your mysql port to which? If you want to know what is the MySQL port, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18353323/1992780).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Fix:

You are passing wrong parameter to `mysql_connect` function, `port` is not a separate parameter. First parameter accept values as `[hostname:port]`. So it should be:

```
mysql_connect($this->host.':'.$this->port, $this->uname, $this->pw);
```

### Reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

### P.S.

*Note: MySQL library is deprecated please use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead*

Comment: Solved it. I'll also consider your suggestion of MySQLi and PDO. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the PDO way.

```
class Db extends \PDO {
    public function __construct() {
        $aDriverOptions[\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND] = 'SET NAMES UTF8';
        parent::__construct('mysql:host=' . Config::DB_HOST . ':80;port=3307;dbname=' . Config::DB_NAME . ';', Config::DB_USR, Config::DB_PWD, $aDriverOptions);
        $this->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
}
```

The most important part is the first parameter of the constructor `'mysql:host=xxx;port=xxx;dbname=xxx'` where you have to specify your other-than-3306 port number. In my case, I used `3307`.